# CheckedComboboxEdit check item does not work properly

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I used a CheckedComboBoxEdit control. It is filled by a dataTable. And I checked an item programatically.The following picture shows the output:

[image: Resulting picture]

It shows that, no items are selected in drop down menu. I did not understand the problem.

**Edit**: I found the source of the problem. However I do not know, how can I fix this and why it causes the problem.

My code:

```
rHOP rGetir = new rHOP();
DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit propertiesBaslattigiSurecler = cceBaslattigiSurecler.Properties;

DataTable dt = rGetir.GetirSurecTanim(0, 0);

dt.Columns.Add("Deger", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
  dt.Rows[i]["Deger"] = dt.Rows[i]["Süreç No"].ToString()
                      + "," + dt.Rows[i]["Sürüm"].ToString();

propertiesBaslattigiSurecler.DataSource = dt;

propertiesBaslattigiSurecler.DisplayMember = "Süreç Ad";
propertiesBaslattigiSurecler.ValueMember = "Deger"; // this line causes the problem
cceBaslattigiSurecler.SetEditValue(null);
```

The dataTable dt has three columns as "Süreç Ad", "Süreç No", "Süreç Ack". Then I added "Deger" column to the dataTable. When I set the ValueMember property to "Deger" column, the problem occurs. When I set the ValueMember property to another column, it works correctly.

Comment: Please update your question with code snippet you using for programmatically item selection...

Comment: +1 I love people when they paste some code